# Paper size setting won't save for Snow Leopard

Tags: google-chrome, printing, osx-snow-leopard, zebra-printers, cups

I am using a Zebra LP 2844 to print barcode labels out of the Chrome browser, as it has good printing support for this purpose.

The one problem that I cannot seem to solve is that the paper size is never maintained after a label has printed.

This is true of other applications as well and seems to be an issue with the OS.

Even if the presets are saved, the paper size always defaults back to US Letter, or in the case of the machine in question, "Other."

I have looked at the plist for that printer as well as the printing plist, and the default paper size is set to the one I created for the Zebra.

However, as soon as that paper size is selected in the print dialog, and the document prints, the next time it prints, the paper size is back to default.

Does anyone know how to defeat this?

I have repaired permissions, deleted plists, etc.

Thanks so much.

Comment: I am starting to learn that it may have something to do with CUPS. But in the PPD file there is no reference to the "Other" size, nor can I find it anywhere else in the OS. Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after many hours of toil, i found the simplest of solutions. simply open TextEdit, go to Page Setup and set up your presets there and click OK.

then File > Print and do the same thing in that window being sure to save a new preset with your customer paper size or any other paper size.

once this is done, these settings should be available in other applications.

there may be another solution, but this worked for me.